# Does class/function order matter in C++?

Tags: c++, function

I'm beginning to learn C++. In the IDE codeblocks, this compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct A {};

struct B {
    A a;
}

void hi() {
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}

int main() {
    hi();
    return 0;
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
struct B {
    A a;
}

struct A {};

int main() {
    hi();
    return 0;
}

void hi() {
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}
```

It gives me the errors:

```
error: 'A' does not name a type
error: 'hi' was not declared in this scope
```

Should class/function order matter in C++? I thought it doesn't. Please clarify the issue.

Comment: Seems like this could be a duplicate...

Comment: Functions should at least be declared before being used. But once you declared them, the order does not matter (or very marginally). For short functions, it might be *slightly* better to group related functions (eg `f` before `g` if `g` calls `f`), perhaps because of cache issues. But this is often irrelevant (and the compiler will often reflush the generated function order).

Comment: I would suggest that you get a book on C++ instead of trying to learn the language by playing in an IDE.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, you must at least *declare* the class/function before you use/call it, even if the actual definition does not come until afterwards.

That is why you often declare the classes/functions in header files, then `#include` them at the top of your cpp file. Then you can use the classes/functions in any order, since they have already been effectively declared.

Note in your case you could have done this. ([working example](http://ideone.com/tKD2r8))

```
void hi();    // This function is now declared

struct A; // This type is now declared

struct B {
    A* a; // we can now have a pointer to it
};

int main() {
    hi();
    return 0;
}

void hi() {    // Even though the definition is afterwards
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}

struct A {}; // now A has a definition
```