# error function not declared in scope

Tags: c++

I'm trying to log a few values to a text file, but everytime I do it, it gives me this error:

[Error] 'save' was not declared in this scope

Here's the code:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "fstream"

using namespace std;
double n1, n2;

int main()
{

    n1 = 1;
    n2 = 2;
    save(n1, n2)

}
int save(double a, double b)
{
    ofstream log;
    log.open("test.txt");
    log << 1 << 2 << "\n";
    log.close();
}
```

I'm new to C++ and programming in general, please explain in an easy way.

Thanks.

Comment: You will get a good understanding if you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration

Comment: [Does function order matter in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26122024/does-function-order-matter-in-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code in `main` needs to know that such a function exists. It needs either a declaration or a definition above it:

```
int save(double a, double b);

int main() //...
```

By the way: you should eschew using global variables. And you're not using the parameters in your `save` function.

Comment: Dont answer this, there are 5 million duplicates to this question, you should vote to close instead.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, worked just fine!

Comment: @Ben okay, I'll try.